# Insert into joined tables mysql node

Tags: mysql, node.js, insert-into

I am new to node and I want to use 4 tables with inner join.

I have a problem with the insert into. Select, delete and update are ok.

```
var database = require('../dbconnection');

addList:function(list, callback){
    return database.query("INSERT INTO list_customers SET c_l_name=?, c_l_name_c_id=? " , [list.c_l_name, list.c_name_id], callback);
}
```

I have an error: Column 'c_l_name_c_id' cannot be null

Primary key is c_name_id not null auto increment
and Foreign key c_l_name_c_id not null

I have c_name_id in Select with the inner join.

Comment: Thank you MirzaS, but I still do not understand why. I put the id, for example c_l_name_c_id=3 and is all ok, but only for one id (3). Can you add a example

Answer (score 0):

The error told you what is the problem. You don't get the `list.c_name_id`, it stays null, and `c_l_name_c_id` is `NOT NULL` in the db. Somewhere in the application you need to check if you even get the `list.c_name_id`, if it's null or not, if it's not null then you can call this function, if it's null return a message or whatever logic you want to implement there.